# Getting ActiveQuery instead of array in Yii2 ActiveRecord

Tags: php, activerecord, yii2

I have this ActiveQuery that should return an array:

```
$logData = VisitorLog::find()
            ->select($reportMetaHash[$selectedType]['select'])
            ->from("visitor_log v");


        foreach($reportMetaHash[$selectedType]['joins'] as $join){

            $logData->join($join['type'],$join['table'],$join['on']);

        }

        $logData->where(['=', 'v.app_id' , $app_id])
            ->andWhere(['=', 'assorted_id' , $selectedType])
            ->andWhere(['>=', 'access_time', $app->start_date])
            ->andWhere('assorted_id IN ('.$selectedType.')')
            ->groupBy("v.access_log_id, v.content_id")
            ->orderBy('b.booth_name, u.`first_name`')
            ->asArray()
            ->all();

        echo '<pre>'; print_r($logData); exit;
```

This return and `ActiveQuery` object instead of an expected array.

But when i add the joins without the loop, like below, i get an array, as expected.

```
$logData = VisitorLog::find()
            ->select($reportMetaHash[$selectedType]['select'])
            ->from("visitor_log v")
            ->join("JOIN", "user u", "u.`app_id`=".$app_id." AND u.id = v.access_log_id AND u.`user_type_id`=8")
            ->join("JOIN", "document d", "d.doc_id = v.`content_id` AND d.`doctypeId` = 1")
            ->join("JOIN", "booths b", "b.booth_id = d.booth_id")
            ->where(['=','v.app_id' , $app_id])
            ->andWhere(['=', 'assorted_id' , $selectedType])
            ->andWhere(['>=', 'access_time', $app->start_date])
            ->andWhere('assorted_id IN ('.$selectedType.')')
            ->groupBy("v.`access_log_id`, v.content_id")
            ->orderBy('b.booth_name, u.`first_name`')
            ->asArray()
            ->all();
```

The chaining should work in the loop just as it does without it i think. What am i doing wrong here?

PS: When i run the the same raw query in SQL it returns correct resultset.

Answer (score 2):

Query result is returned by `all()` call - this method does not modify query object, it just returns the results. You should pass its result to variable:

```
$result = $logData->where(['=', 'v.app_id' , $app_id])
    ->andWhere(['=', 'assorted_id' , $selectedType])
    ->andWhere(['>=', 'access_time', $app->start_date])
    ->andWhere('assorted_id IN ('.$selectedType.')')
    ->groupBy("v.access_log_id, v.content_id")
    ->orderBy('b.booth_name, u.`first_name`')
    ->asArray()
    ->all();

echo '<pre>'; print_r($result); exit;
```